In Next.js, how can I make a link active and scroll to a specific section on the same page using an ID when clicked?
I want to implement a functionality in Next.js where:
When a user clicks on a link, it scrolls to a specific section on the same page.
The link becomes active (e.g., changes color, gets an underline, etc.) when clicked and scrolled to the corresponding section.
The scrolling is done using an ID, which means the link has an href attribute with the ID of the section it should scroll to.
This is my code
<ul className = "font-medium flex flex-col p-4 md:p-0 mt-4  md:flex-row md:space-x-8 rtl:space-x-reverse md:mt-0 transition-all" > {
    navLinks.map((link, index) => {
      return ( 
     <li key = {index} >
        <Link href = {`#${link.path}`}
        scroll className = {cn("block py-2 px-3 text-white  rounded md:bg-transparent md:text-blue-700 md:p-0 dark:text-white hover:dark:text-blue-500 transition-all")}
        aria-current = "page" >
        {
          link.name
        } 
        </Link> 
      </li>
      );
    })
  } </ul>

Expected Behavior:
When a user clicks on a link with an href attribute containing an ID (e.g., #section1), the page should scroll to the element with the corresponding ID (e.g., ).
The link that was clicked should become active, which could be achieved by adding a CSS class to the link element or modifying its styles in some way.

This is how you can do achieve this
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import cn from 'classnames'; // Import for conditionally applying class names

const Navbar = ({ navLinks }) => {
  const [activeSection, setActiveSection] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      const scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
      navLinks.forEach((link) => {
        const section = document.getElementById(link.path);
        if (section && scrollPosition >= section.offsetTop - 80 && scrollPosition < section.offsetTop + section.offsetHeight) {
          setActiveSection(link.path);
        }
      });
    };

    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, [navLinks]);

  return (
    <ul className="font-medium flex flex-col p-4 md:p-0 mt-4 md:flex-row md:space-x-8 rtl:space-x-reverse md:mt-0 transition-all">
      {navLinks.map((link, index) => (
        <li key={index}>
          <Link href={`#${link.path}`} scroll={false}>
            <a
              className={cn(
                "block py-2 px-3 text-white rounded md:bg-transparent md:text-blue-700 md:p-0 dark:text-white transition-all",
                activeSection === link.path && "underline text-blue-500" // Add active class here
              )}
              aria-current={activeSection === link.path ? "page" : undefined}
            >
              {link.name}
            </a>
          </Link>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default Navbar;


and the section where you want to perform the scroll
<div id="section1" className="section">
  <h1>Section 1</h1>
  <p>Content for Section 1</p>
</div>

<div id="section2" className="section">
  <h1>Section 2</h1>
  <p>Content for Section 2</p>
</div>

